# How to run something in the dialog code by pressing F5, F6, F10?

Tags: bash, dialog

How to run something in the dialog code by pressing F5, F6, F10?

```
dialog --menu "Menu items" 0 0 0 .....

RET=$?

case $RET in
 0) press button OK;;
 1) press button Cancel;;
 255) press button Esc;;
 ???) press button F5;;
 ???) press button F6;;
 ???) press button F10;;
esac
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Not with the way you're doing it unfortunately. That's grabbing the exit code of `dialog`, which unfortunately isn't going to be bindable to the keys you want (the closest thing you could have would be to map a single function key to Esc but that only gives you one key).

At this point you either have the choice of hacking the dialog code directly or using language of choice and ncurses backend to achieve that.